# Character styles in docbook 5

Tags: xml, docbook, docbook-5

What are the character styles in docbook 5? I know there are paragraph styles which are sect1-title, sect2-title, etc. I want to know what character styles are there. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how you can apply formatting such as bold, underline or colour to inline text? If that is not what you mean, please explain.

Comment: @mzjn yes you are correct. That's what I mean. I managed to do it when the text is either bold 'or' italic. But when I have bold 'and' italic, bold 'and' underline, italic 'and' underline I do not know how to apply them. Aren't such styles supported? If supported can you tell me how to apply them? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using stylesheets, you can define as many "character styles" as you like. The set of stylesheets that most people use (available from the [DocBook SourceForge project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/)) provide default styling for many inline elements. There is no exhaustive list detailing any "standard" styles, but it is fairly easy to customize the output to your liking.

A style such as "italics + underline" is not supported by default, but you can add it if you want. By convention, the `role` attribute is used to provide a classification ("stylesheet hint") for an element. See http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CustomInlines.html for more details.

---

It is worth emphasizing that DocBook markup (the elements and attributes defined in a schema) is not concerned with "styles". DocBook is a [semantic markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook) and a key concept is that you define/describe what something is rather than what it should look like.

Comment: Thanks a lot mzjn! :) I've been looking for this.